# How can I lock the pump of a JASON soap pump bottle?

Tags: travel

Currently abroad, I bought a JASON Body Wash bottle pump, as I thought I'd use all the soap but there remains a lot. 
 How can I lock or fasten the pump before I pack the pump in my luggage, to prevent the pump from being accidentally triggered and spewing soap?

When I first bought this pump bottle, the pump was lowered (see screenshot under). But for my first use, I had to raise the pump that's been upright ever since. I can't depress the pump at all, as pressing down  spews soap.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There’s a tiny screw thread just under the head, where the nozzle piece joins the stem. You’ll need to ‘waste’ (or use) one pump or so of soap.

Push the head all the way down, then twist it clockwise to lock. If it doesn’t lock, twist it the other way.

Note that with all the jostling in the baggage during transport, the dispenser can easily unlock. After the push-twist to lock the nozzle down, you can try keeping the nozzle in place with sticky tape.

(As @BrettFromLA [notes](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/20236/how-can-i-lock-the-pump-of-a-jason-soap-pump-bottle#comment29938_20238), seal the bottle in something like a Ziploc bag after the above.)

Comment: Upvote. Also, the traveler should put the soap bottle in a tightly-sealed waterproof bag (like a Ziploc) after locking the pump.

Comment: Thanks @BrettFromLA! I've added your note to my answer.

Comment: Thanks again. How can I feel or sense the locking, and once the nozzle has locked?

Comment: @Antinatalist There’s a bit of resistance as the thread engages. When it stops moving, don’t force it any further.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen multiple videos online (I can't google now tho), where it shows how to do this:

Take a rubberband, then push the bottle so that the "button" is lowered, fix it with the rubberband so it won't go up again.

Try googling: "Lock soap with rubberband"